# animation-fill-mode not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Im trying to get a header to fly in and after that when you hover it, it should shake (both with css3 animation). It flies in the way i want, also shakes, but after ive removed the mouse from the element it goes back to the original margin-right (it had before the flyin animation) even though ive set `-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
When i look in chromedevtools the element never changes its margin-right (even though the animation works..). Can i fix this?

Also, is there a way of preventing the first animation to happen again after the shake animation?

flyin animation:

```
#name {
margin:40px 2% 40px 0;

-webkit-animation:flyin 1.5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-delay: 1800ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flyin {

from{margin-right: 2%;}
30% {margin-right: 12%;}
50% {margin-right: 9%;}
60% {margin-right: 10%;}
to {margin-right: 10%;}
}
```

shake animation:

```
#name:hover {
        **margin-right: 10%; //i also have to set this?! or it starts at 2%**
        -webkit-animation:shake 0.7s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; 
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;


    }

    @-webkit-keyframes shake { 
0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); } 
10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); } 
20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); } 
30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); } 
40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); } 
50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); } 
60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); } 
70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); } 
80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); } 
90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); } 
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); } 
}
```

Comment: if i add this in js 100ms after the animation is finished it works... but thats very ugly: document.getElementById("name").style.marginRight = "10%";

Comment: here you go http://codepen.io/tobbbe/pen/ozlKc (yes i know the animation is ugly, gonna fix it later)

Answer (score 10):

Setting `animation-fill-mode: forwards` means that after the animation has completed execution, the animation will hold at final properties until it is removed. When the mouse stops hovering, the `-webkit-animation` property returns to its default value (blank), which means that the `shake` animation is removed, and everything returns to how it was. To make the animation hold its final properties, you have to keep the `shake` animation applied to the element. (In other words, `animation-fill-mode` is effective only as long as the animation is applied.)

Comment: hmm, ok i think i understand. But how should i keep the shake animation applied to the element?

Comment: @tobbe One option is to apply it programmatically when the hover begins and never remove it.

Comment: The value of the animation-fill-mode property is with s at the end => insted forward => forwards

Answer (score 1):

To make the animation hold at its state when mouse is leaving element, you need to add all animation properties to an element in **normal state**, **not** `:hover`, plus:

`animation-play-state: paused`

On `:hover` add only:

`animation-play-state: running`