# CSS3 Animation repeating again and again

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to write an animation which will make `.hint` div disappear when hovered on.

Here is a [live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oDIaF) of what I've tried.
But, the animation keeps continuing again and again, even after adding a `animation-iteration-count:1;` at the end. The Codepen uses prefixfree.js so no vendor prefixes are used in my code.

How do I make the animation stop after only 1 iteration?

## EDIT

I want the `.hint` to stay opacity:0 when the cursor is not over it.

Comment: You mean you want it to remain at `opacity: 0` when it is still being hovered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the animation's fill mode as `forwards`. This will make the animation hold the state that was executed by the last `keyframe` which is (`opacity: 0;`)

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

---

If you want it to remain at `opacity: 0;` even after the mouse leaves the element after one hover, add a class for `opacity: 0;` like below and attach it to the element `onmouseleave` using jQuery.

Also, remember you cannot use CSS `hover` in that case because if `:hover` rule is specified it will trigger the animation even when `opacity` is `0` and mouse is moved over the position where the element would have been. Instead you should have a `class` as `hover` and attach it only once to the element like I have shown below using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hint').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.hint').addClass('alreadyHovered');
  });
  $('.hint').on('mouseover', function() {
    if (!($('.hint').hasClass('alreadyHovered'))) {
      $('.hint').addClass('hover');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes vanish {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes vanish {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes vanish {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.hint {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #E51400;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10px;
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}
.hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: vanish;
  -moz-animation-name: vanish;
  animation-name: vanish;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
.alreadyHovered {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hint">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Strange. I don't use Chrome. In Opera 15, IE10 and Firefox 23 it does.

Comment: @svineet: I tested in Chrome 31 (dev version) and there also it works.

Comment: It does work for me (Firefox 24)! Apparently, `animation-fill-mode: both;` seems to work too, but I don't know why. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode this is still an 'experimental technology', so, maybe you should not rely too much on it working in all browsers?

Comment: @cars10: Yeah, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) says that animations does work in Chrome with `-webkit` prefix. But that is not needed for this pen as indicated by OP in comments.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573312/animation-fill-mode-not-working). See the answer, It says that animation-fill-mode needs to stay a property of the class, but here it gets removed when :hover ends. I tried using JS, to set it right, but still not working.

Comment: It is when you want it to hold the state even after moving out. But your comments in OP stated otherwise.

Comment: Thank you and sorry that my question was ambiguous

Comment: @svineet: Never mind mate :) Don't feel bad, it happens to all of us.